LP relaxation for min cost perfect matching
I'm not able to see what I'm doing wrong in the following argument, could someone please help me?
Define $S:=\{D \subseteq V:|D|$ is odd}.
According to the theorem 5.13 in combinatorial optimization by Cook et al, a graph G has perfect matching iff the following LP (P) is feasible:
$\min \sum_{e\in E}c_ex_e$ s.t $\hspace{.5cm}$
$x(\delta(v))=1 \hspace{.1cm}\forall v \in V$, $\hspace{.4cm}$ $x(\delta(D))\geq 1 \hspace{.1cm}\forall D \in S$, $\hspace{.3cm} x\geq0$
Now, the feasibility of the primal is not dependent on the objective function, so we can make a new LP (P') with the same feasible solution set, but with objective function 0. So, P is feasible iff P' is feasible. Now, every feasible solution to P' is optimal, so P' is feasible iff P' has an optimal solution iff Dual (D') of (P') has a feasible solution with objective value 0.  Now, (D') is $\max \sum_{v \in V}y_v+\sum_{D\in S}y_D$ s.t $\hspace{.3cm}$
$y_u+y_v+\sum_{D\in S:e \in \delta(D)}y_D \leq0 $ for all e=uv $\in E$,$\hspace{.4cm} y_D \geq 0 \forall D \in S.$
Now, y=0 is always an optimal solution to D', so P' is always feasible, and consequently P is always feasible, this is however nonsensical. Could someone please point out the flaw in my argument?
Theorem 5.13 snapshot
Dual of the LP relaxation

Although $y=0$ is always feasible to the dual, the dual might be unbounded, in which case the primal is infeasible.

Ah! I missed that, thanks a lot!

Glad to help. Please mark my answer as accepted.
